# Div shows upper half of the text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a project in MVC 5 , I have a page where I have to display a description about an item, the description sometimes can be long so I have to restrict it to 500 characters initially and put a read more button, the read more button displays the full description.

I am using Readmore.js to achieve this. Its working fine for me, but there is a small issue (CSS might be). The issue arises when the resolution is between 320 and 768. The last line is shown as half texted. see image below.

The description text is being taken from the database and it has one or more than one paragraphs enclosed in paragraph tags.

[image]

The the height of the div is **195px**

**Mark Up**

```
<div class="float-left">
     <h1 class="contentTile">
           Description
     </h1>
     <div class="appDescription">

            @Html.Raw(Model.Description)

      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="buttonsContainer">
          <a class="articleBtn float-right" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:none">Read More</a>
      </div>

</div>
```

**script**

```
var totalChars = 0;
var parg = $('.appDescription').find('p');
if (parg.length) {
    $('.appDescription').find('p').each(function (index) {
        totalChars += $(this).text().length;
    });
} else {
    totalChars = $('.appDescription').text().length;
}
 if (totalChars >= 500) {
    $('.appDescription').readmore({
        moreLink: '<a class="articleBtn float-right" id="readmoreBtn" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:15px" href="javascript:void(0);" >Read More</a>',
        lessLink: '<a class="articleBtn float-right" id="showlessBtn"  href="javascript:void(0);">Show Less</a>',
        embedCSS: true,
        collapsedHeight: 195,
        blockCSS: 'width:auto;',
        afterToggle: function () {
            $('#showlessBtn').css({
                'margin-top': '10px',
                'margin-bottom': '15px'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Decrease the height of the div or increase line-height of text by 1px or 2px

Comment: can u create a fiddle example for this

Comment: Thanks @ArunKumarM ,, it fixed the issue on all resolutions by setting line-height to 1.3em..